# Issue with Double quote chars in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My source file is as below, I am trying to read this in pyspark for further transformations.

```
"ID","FNAME","LNAME","AGE","DESIGNATION"

"1","John","Denver","34","Tech Staff"

"2","Philip","Spencer","30","Tech Staff "CONTRACT""
```

**Screenshot of the data is :**

[image]

The code is below

```
%pyspark

df = spark.read.csv("s3://emp_bucket/test_files/emp.csv",sep=",",quote='"',header='true')

df.show(truncate=False)
```

**I am expecting the out to be as below:**

```
+---+------+-------+---+-----------------------+

|ID |FNAME |LNAME  |AGE|DESIGNATION            |

+---+------+-------+---+-----------------------+

|1  |John  |Denver |34 |Tech Staff             |

|2  |Philip|Spencer|30 |Tech Staff "CONTRACT"|

+---+------+-------+---+-----------------------+
```

**But the out is something unexpected as below:**

```
+---+------+-------+---+-----------------------+

|ID |FNAME |LNAME  |AGE|DESIGNATION            |

+---+------+-------+---+-----------------------+

|1  |John  |Denver |34 |Tech Staff             |

|2  |Philip|Spencer|30 |"Tech Staff "CONTRACT""|

+---+------+-------+---+-----------------------+
```

I tried using escape chars but pyspark is unable to avoid the outer double quotes in **"Tech Staff "CONTRACT""**.

Can someone see if this is the valid behaviour please?

Comment: You forgot to add a screenshot of the file content - maybe the problem is in the file.

Comment: My source file is exactly as given in the beginning of the question.

Comment: Added formatting to clarify.

Comment: `"Tech Staff "CONTRACT""` is wrong, there is no escaping.

Comment: Are you suggesting the data itself is wrong? But I have the text qualifiers defined as double quotes so the Ideal behaviour should be spark reading the data with out outer double quotes isn't it?

Comment: In CSV, the quotes are for wrapping fields, especially fields with commas, however, fields with quotes inside need escaping of the quotes with a slash (and slashes need escaping too).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the row:

```
"2","Philip","Spencer","30","Tech Staff "CONTRACT""
```

You will see the quotes in the last column aren't escaped.

It should be:

```
"2","Philip","Spencer","30","Tech Staff \"CONTRACT\""
```

or even unquoted (as there are no commas in the content):

```
2,Philip,Spencer,30,Tech Staff \"CONTRACT\"
```

Comment: So I have tried this but its not working.  
|1  |John  |Denver |34 |Tech Staff              |
|2  |Philip|Spencer|30 |"Tech Staff "CONTRACT\""|

Comment: Still missing one slash